# Making turtle draw a square with a loop

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm learning about classes on Udacity and we started by learning `turtle`. There was an exercise where you were supposed not to repeat

```
brad.forward(100)
brad.right(90)
```

four times (Brad is the turtle's name), and instead create a loop. My guess was:

```
while True:
    brad.forward(100)
    brad.right(90)
    if turtle.position() == (0,0):
        break
```

However, Brad just draws the first, upper line. What am I getting wrong? If needed, the full code is below. Thank you!

```
import turtle

def square():
    turtle.colormode(255)
    window = turtle.Screen()
    window.bgcolor(0,0,0)
    #meet brad
    brad = turtle.Turtle()
    brad.shape('arrow')
    brad.speed(1)
    brad.color(0,255,255)
    #brad creates a square
    while True:
        brad.forward(100)
        brad.right(90)
        if turtle.position() == (0,0):
            break
    turtle.exitonclick()

square()
```

Comment: Could you clarify including the "correct" code without using a loop?

Comment: Im not familiar with Udacity but my guess is 0,0 is the top right and you're starting in the top left. Try `if turtle.position() == (100,0):` maybe?

Comment: @DanielCentore brad.forward(100) \ brad.right(90) was repeated 4x instead of the loop.

Comment: @Mitchel0022 It did work insofar as the turtle drew the full square, but now the loop goes on forever. The same goes for (-100,0).

Comment: @RenanAndrade what is the initial starting position of this turtle? You could try saying `initPos = turtle.position()` before the loop then loop until `turtle.position() == initPos`

Comment: Another solution would be to replace the while with `for _ in range(4)`

Comment: @Mitchel0022 I embbed a print(turtle.position()) to the function and it got (0,0).

Comment: The for loop worked! Thanks :)

Comment: Look at my answer, I think I found what was wrong with your original solution

Answer (score 3):

replace `turtle.position` with `brad.position`. You are checking a generic turtle object not the one you created

Comment: On my system, this fix loops forever. A possible reason is that the turtle wanders a floating point plane so you don't always come back to *exactly* where you started.  The fix likely involves using `brad.distance(start_position)` to see if you're close to your starting point or ignoring the starting point and using a fixed number of iterations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop which just runs it 4 times then:

```
import turtle

def square():
    turtle.colormode(255)
    window = turtle.Screen()
    window.bgcolor(0,0,0)
    #meet brad
    brad = turtle.Turtle()
    brad.shape('arrow')
    brad.speed(1)
    brad.color(0,255,255)
    #brad creates a square
    for _ in range(4):
        brad.forward(100)
        brad.right(90)
    turtle.exitonclick()

square()
```

Answer (score 1):

Via *stamping*, we can make the square with no repeated statements nor loop:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

def square():
    # meet brad
    brad = Turtle('square', visible=False)
    brad.color('cyan', 'black')
    # brad creates a square
    brad.shapesize(100 / CURSOR_SIZE)
    brad.stamp()

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('black')

square()

screen.exitonclick()
```

Though likely not the solution you were looking for, there are some turtle idioms in the code you might find useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
import turtle

def square():
    turtle.colormode(255)
    window = turtle.Screen()
    window.bgcolor(0,0,0)
    #meet brad
    brad = turtle.Turtle()
    brad.shape('arrow')
    brad.speed(1)
    brad.color(0,255,255)
    #brad creates a square
    start_position = brad.position()
    while True:
        brad.forward(100)
        brad.right(90)
        if brad.position() == start_position:
            break
    brad.exitonclick()

square()
```

Comment: On my system, this loops forever.  A possible reason is that the turtle wanders a floating point plane so you don't always come back to exactly where you left.  Using something like `brad.distance(start_position) < 0.5` might be safer.  Also, had it not looped forever, it would have broken on the next line as `'Turtle' object has no attribute 'exitonclick'`.

Comment: I tried something similar on https://trinket.io/python and it works as expected but right now it in infinite loop as you described.

What is strange is if I do something like brad.home() and then save the start_position with brad.position, the while loop works as expected.